# sort results given by find command

Tags: linux, shell, find, ls, xargs

this is the find command:

```
find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409*' -type f| xargs ls -lhrt |awk '{print $9}' > log.txt
```

this is the set of files i'm looking for, these ones can be 7 thousands of files which are being directed to 'xargs', i'm just listing the first part, middle and the last part

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 see  seegrp  100K Feb 12 00:00 VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409000000_000760000.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 see  seegrp  193K Feb 12 00:01 VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409000000_000760001.txt
.
.
-rw-rw-r-- 1 see  seegrp  193K Feb 12 10:03 VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409174500_000764500.txt
.
.
-rw-rw-r-- 1 see  seegrp   95K Feb 12 23:59 VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409235500_000766488.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 see  seegrp  103K Feb 12 23:59 VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409235500_000766489.txt
```

later this is the tar for compressing:

```
tar -czf cdr_backup.tar.gz -T log.txt
```

The problem appears when doing the log using this way because the results on the log.txt file are not sorted correctly, i think it is because of some xargs limitation

code:

```
number=$(more log.txt |wc -l)
echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
echo "Start Time : $DATETIME">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
echo "Tar file created: $FILE">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
echo "Tar file contains $number CDRs backed up successfully">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
firstline=$(head -n 1 log.txt)
echo "from this sequence $firstline ">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
lastline=$(tail -1 log.txt)
echo "to this one $lastline">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
echo "Finish Time : $FINISHTIME">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
```

Output generated:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Start Time : 20140410 15:16:24
Tar file created: cdr_backup.tar.gz
Tar file contains 7720 CDRs backed up successfully
from this sequence ./VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409000000_000741343.txt
to this one ./VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409174500_000764500.txt
Finish Time : 20140410 15:23:42
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Note that the last sequence is not the one should be

```
VPN_CALLRECORD_20140409235500_000766489.txt
```

why? i'm not sure, i tried to sort the results in the log.txt file so this

```
lastline=$(tail -1 ${TEMPFILE})
```

can work, but it is not possible, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Xargs will split the number of incoming arguments to avoid creating too long command lines. Also, the output of "find" will not be sorted in any way. If you want to sort, insert a call to "sort" in the pipe (for example, at the end.)

Comment: sort can't be used because there could be a lot of files created at the same time i.e. above two last files were created at 23:59, so how thouse ones can be sorted? i meant using the time column as criteria

Comment: @Patricio_Estrella Something like `sort < <(find -printf "%T@ %p\n")`though I'm not sure if you're going to have buffering issues in this case. May need to kick output over to a file and then sort.

Comment: How do you *want* the files to be sorted? You have to be able to actually define a sort order. When you say "sorted correctly," what is the definition of "correctly" ?

Comment: hi i want to be sorted by date, based on your entries i made this `prFEP1a:/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile # more script_for_log.sh
#!/bin/sh
firstline=$(find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD_20140410*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1 -n |head -n 1|awk '{print $2}')
lastline=$(find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD_20140410*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1 -n |tail -1|awk '{print $2}')
echo $firstline
echo $lastline
prFEP1a:/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile # sh script_for_log.sh
./VPN_CALLRECORD_20140410000000_000766490.txt
./VPN_CALLRECORD_20140410235500_000775310.txt`